# Convert FilePart to BufferedReader

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I read tons of post on this same problem: how to access data within a FilePart. I saw a lot of answers but none of them is suitable for my case.

The method in my controller is:

```
@PostMapping("/importData")
    public List<BulkImportResponse<ContainerBulkImportObj>> importData(@RequestPart(value = "file", required = true) FilePart file) {

        log.debug("[importData] BEGIN ");

        List<BulkImportResponse<ContainerBulkImportObj>> result = new ArrayList<>();
        try {

            PipedOutputStream osPipe = new PipedOutputStream();
            PipedInputStream isPipe = new PipedInputStream(osPipe);
            DataBufferUtils.write(file.content(), osPipe).doOnComplete(() -> {
                try {
                    osPipe.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    log.error("", e);
                }
            }).subscribe(DataBufferUtils.releaseConsumer());

            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(isPipe));

            result = bulkImportService.importData(bufferedReader);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            log.error("[importData] An error occured during execution:", ex);
        }

        log.debug("[importData] END ");

        return result;
    }
```

The problem is that when receiving a file it never exits from the DataBufferUtils.write block. It remains there forever.

Do you have any suggestions how to solve this problem?

Comment: Nobody is reading the pipe, so it blocks. What exactly are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: I would like to read the content of the FilePart into a BufferedReader, that I'll use with openCSV in bulkImportService.importData

Comment: But you don’t need pipes for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found the solution on this site:

https://manhtai.github.io/posts/flux-databuffer-to-inputstream/

I was missing the

```
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.elastic())
```

as first instruction after the *DataBufferUtils.write(file.content(), osPipe)*, before the *doOnComplete*.